# Once a Character exceeds Wound Threshold, do they gain a new Critical Injury each time they take damage?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny, injury, fumbles

**Edge of the Empire Core Book, Pg 215 : Exceeding Wound Threshold**

> When a PC suffers wounds greater than their wound threshold, they are knocked out and incapacitated until their wounds are reduced so they no longer exceed their wound threshold.
>
> They also immediately suffer one Critical Injury.

Assume a character has already received enough Wounds to exceed their Wound Threshold and has thus been rendered Incapacitated and received one Critical Injury.  Combat continues to ensure and an NPC chooses to attack this character causing them to take damage.

Does this new damage mean the character immediately suffers an additional Critical Injury?

Would continued instances of damage continue to accumulate Critical Injuries until the character reaches the maximum of exceeding their Threshold by twice its total?

Answer (score 11):

From the [Developer Answered Questions](https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/topic/108101-ffg-developer-answered-questions/) thread on the FFG Forums (found inside the *General Combat Question* collapse):

> Rules as written a character would not suffer a second Critical Injury if the character takes more damage and is already incapacitated.
>
> However, since the character is incapacitated and cannot defend himself, the GM would be perfectly within his rights to allow the second hit to inflict an automatic Critical Injury, or any other nasty effects depending on the circumstances.
>
> If the character is being shot at point blank range while lying helpless on the ground, for example, the GM could simply skip the Critical Injuries altogether, and proceed directly to complete, unrecoverable death.